# Does anyone know if it's possible to integrate carrierwave backgrounder (store_in_background) with Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder

I would like to use `store_in_background` method for delaying storing the files to the S3 but I'm little bit afraid as Heroku is read only system and wondering if anyone has managed that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work iff you're using Heroku's newer stack which offers an ephemeral file system. I'd recommend something like queue_classic instead of carrierwave_backgrounder.

Queue Classic uses Postgres-specific features to deliver great performance. It also has the advantage of being able to be modified by postgres triggers/procedures. This allows you to queue an image delete when an image row is deleted in ONE query.

Comment: My concern is the files from /tmp directory will be destroyed after the request.